# Visual Studio Code Extension for remote debugging PL/I on z/OS

Tags: remote-debugging, vscode-debugger, mainframe

we want to write a VSCode debug extension for remote debugging PL/I source code on the mainframe.

We use IBM's z/OS Explorer, but we don't want to start this heavy Eclipse bundle for debugging (everything else is done in this VSCode extension).

We "wiresharked" the communication with IBM's z/OS Explorer, so it would be no problem to send and receive tcp packages according what the debugger (running on the mainframe) needs.

But we don't understand how debugging could work in a VSCode extension.

Now it is working as following:

1. Write a dataset on the mainframe
2. Submit a job with the program you want to debug
3. When the z/OS Explorer is started, debugging is starting.

What is needed to
1.) init vscode debugging functions
2.) send start command via tcp
3.) receive and display the information via tcp
4.) start, stop and breakpoint functionalities

Any examples etc. would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: I don't think there will be an easy way to implement an own debug-client plugin for VSCode. IBM is providing one, but I think it is only available as part of IBM Wazi Developer, so not free of (extra) charge.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you will be able to do this is with WAZi developer. You MUST have the IBM Debugger installed on the z/OS, and that is a licensable program. Yes, you could write a debugger on your own, but the cost/benefit grossly exceeds the price of IBM's licenses.
Here's the details on debugging with WAZi
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/developer-for-zos/15.0.0?topic=code-debugging-applications